# Fill The ForeignKey Field in Django CreateView Automatically

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views, create-view

Here is my scenario. I want one of my model fields to be auto-fill based on whether the user is authenticated or not. Like when the user submits the form, I need to check if the user is authenticated and then fill the `created_by` field up with `<User Object>` otherwise, leave it `Null` if possible.

Here is my model:

```py
class Snippet(models.Model):
    # ---
    create_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
    )
    # ---
```

Here is my view:

```py
class SnippetCreateView(CreateView):
    # ---
        def save(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
                request.POST['create_by'] = user       # --->> TraceBack: due to immutability..
            return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
    # ---
```

Since the `request.POST` QueryDict is immutable, how can I implement it?? I have tried multiple ways like creating a copy of that but nothing happens and it doesn't change anything.

### But..

I can implement it like this and it works with no problem. I think this solution is dirty enough to find a better way. What do you think about this solution??

```py
class Snippet.CreateView(CreateView):
    # ---
        def save(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
            data = {
                'title': request.POST['title'],
                # ---
                'create_by': user if user else None,
            }
            
            snippet = Snippet.objects.create(**data).save()
            # redirecting to Snippet.get_absolute_url()
    # ---
```

Comment: The way you did is not dirty.

Comment: I think It is. I'm overriding the write method. Basically, this method collects my data, saves them, and redirects me to the exact snippet detail page by default. With this solution, I'm re-doing all those steps again which is weird. Isn't it??

Comment: and `snippet = Snippet.objects.create(**data).save()` is not so beautifull. just this `snippet = Snippet.objects.create(**data)` is enough.because inside `.create()` will call `.save()`

Comment: @amadousow, overall, what do you think about that solution?? Rewriting the whole save method instead of adding only one field {`create_by`: user} to `request.POST `??

Answer (score 2):

This solution is applied only if you are using django ModelForm.

```
class CreateArticle(CreateView):
    model = Snippet

    ......... 
    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = self.request.user
        form.instance.created_by = user if user else None
        return super(CreateArticle, self).form_valid(form)
    ......
```